# Reg Ex: Match a word before the dash in a URL

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match multiple URLs with the following structure:

/color-deals/best-color-deals/blue-deals/

I want the RegEx to grab all URLs with this structure regardless of the specific color at the end of the URL, but I need the colors included. For example, blue-deals, yellow-deals, red-deals, etc.

I've tried several combinations, but it doesn't seem very clean to me. Could someone confirm I did this in a way that's clean? The RegEx tester tells me it's grabbing what I want, but it still feels like it could be better.

`\/color-deals\/best-color-deals\/((blue|yellow|green|pink)(\-deals\/$))`

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is just fine, if you might not want the capturing group, we can make it non-captured, and also for the ending trailing slash, just in case, if that might have been optional, we'd add a `?` so that it'd become so:

```
\/color-deals\/best-color-deals\/(?:blue|yellow|green|pink)-deals\/?$
```

Other than that, looks great.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iBmrrG/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/iBmrrG/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]